# History of runned Reports

Tags: java, sdk, cognos

I am working with **Cognos 11.2.2** for the first time and I need to get the history of the runned reports using **Java SDK**, i looked at the samples provided by IBM and I only found how to list all reports (name and searchpath) but there is no explanation how to get history.
Any help or code example would be appreciated.

Note: I tried the ViewAll code and got a list of reports but i did not success extracting history.

Comment: This question is confusing.  Are you saying you want to use product Y, or are you saying you want to accomplish outcome X?  The problem being that product Y may not help you accomplish outcome X.

Comment: i want to get the history of runned reports using cognos SDK (Java)

Comment: Good luck.  I wouldn't use SDK to get that info.